# changing load mode for hazelcast map

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to change the load mode for a Hazelcast 3.2 map.  This is what I have tried via the code (not sure if its available via the XML config file which would be preferable for me).

```
private InitialLoadMode initialLoadMode = InitialLoadMode.EAGER;
final Config config= new Config();
final MapConfig mapConfig = config.getMapConfig("*");
final MapStoreConfig mapStoreConfig = mapConfig.getMapStoreConfig();
mapStoreConfig.setInitialLoadMode(initialLoadMode); //mapStoreConfig.InitialLoadMode(initialLoadMode);
```

The last last line does not appear to compile.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you're classpath only contains the correct JAR versions?

Comment: using the latest stable version.  I am using the all jar file - trying client and server separately to see if it makes a difference

Comment: actually got a null pointer exception regardless of whether I was using a server or client connection

Comment: more working examples of apps with hazelcast 3 (not just upgrades from previous ones) would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call it in a construtor, e.g. :

```
class Foo{

    private InitialLoadMode initialLoadMode = InitialLoadMode.EAGER;
    final Config config= new Config();
    final MapConfig mapConfig = config.getMapConfig("*");
    final MapStoreConfig mapStoreConfig = mapConfig.getMapStoreConfig();
    {
        mapStoreConfig.setInitialLoadMode(initialLoadMode);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.  thought I'd confirm - does this go inside my model class which I am then using as a value in my hazelcast map?  Can I possibly insert this via the xml config file since I am using the config for everything else.

Comment: I got a null pointer exception - does it make a different for testing purposes to use either a client or instance or server (of hazelcast instance)?

Comment: actually got a null pointer exception regardless of whether I was using a server or client connection

Comment: I still get a null pointer exception with initialLoadMode.  However, when I tried my sample app without setting this property, at least the server was able to invoke the store load when calling the map (without calling anything on the map).  I have not been able to try that with the client config (since I am usnig FileSystemXmlConfig which I could not get to work with ClientConfig).