# hazelcast put on IMap not working

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am sure I am doing something wrong but can't see to figure it out.  The hazelcast xml config is copied below for the map.  When I do a put on the map, I can see that the count increases on the map but later on, when I get a reference to the same map, the size appears to be zero.  I am testing on just one node to test my logic.  I am using hazelcast 3.2.  I did not add any store load or listener implementations (I guess I can add the listener to confirm if the entry is added or not).

```
<map name="testMap">
    <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    <backup-count>0</backup-count>
    <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy</merge-policy>
</map>
```

**Sample code**:
I am getting a reference to hazelcast as follows:

```
static HazelCastClientAccessor hazelcastClientAccessor = HazelCastClientAccessor.getAccessorInstance();
static HazelcastInstance hazelcast = hazelcastClientAccessor.getHazelCastInstance();
```

Once I get the reference, I call put or get on the map.

```
IMap<String, String> testMap = hcast.getMap("testMap"); 
testMap.put("abc", "xyz");
```

Then in another class, I get the reference to hazelcast again as mentioned above.  Then I get the map and call get on it but the map is empty.  Any ideas where I am messing up?

```
IMap<String, String> testMap = hcast.getMap("testMap"); 
        for (String s: testMap.keySet()) {
            Logger.info("keys + values{} {}:", s, testMap.get(s));
        }
```

I am fetching an instance of Hazelcast like this:

```
Config config = new FileSystemXmlConfig("somelocation/conf/hazelcast.xml"); //location is correct
HazelcastInstance hazelcast = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
```

Comment: I attached the listener to the map and the entryAdded in the listener got invoked - I can see the key and value in there.

Comment: I also tried just a Map instead of IMap when I try to get the map (after the put operation) - I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong

Comment: I am sure I'm doing something wrong but judging by the interest or lack thereof in getting answers here, I should have picked a different tool instead of hazelcast

Comment: Can you post the logging. Especially the part where the cluster is formed. A potential cause could be that there are 2 seperate clusters and then a change in one won't be visible in another.

Comment: If you can create a unit test that reproduces the issue, it would help us a lot. But this basic example you give it should work; so my guess there is an issue somewhere else (e.g. cluster forming).

Comment: @pveentjer - this is on a single node.  I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong but need to understand what.  I'm testing using the server and not the client right now (so there are no other nodes).  I essentially do a put in one class based on a REST call (this class has a static hazelcast server reference as a class variable), then on another REST call, it calls another class (hazelcast static reference is class variable), in the class method, I use hazelcast.getMap on the map name and then call size on the map.

Comment: @pveentjer - cluster size is 1

Comment: I will check - most likely the class I'm using to spawn the hazelcast server is at fault.  I will use the client to connect to the single node server.

Comment: @pveentjer few things.  When I use the ClientConfig, I cannot use the FileSystemXmlConfig. I need to load the maps in EAGER mode & we had this discussion on a separate thread which did not work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619171/changing-load-mode-for-hazelcast-map).  I am using Properties props = System.getProperties(); props.setProperty("hazelcast.config", "C:/Users/xyz/conf/"); but I get class not found exceptions on my store load.

Comment: the previous issue could be related to 3.2.4 client connecting to 3.2.3 server.  I am now using same server and client and will update the post

Comment: I switched over to the client config and now I'm not seeing the issue.  I think the issue was related to how I was getting a hazelcastinstance - I had switched over from client to server (within my application) but now have reverted to client mode.  Now i need to check if my EAGER mode is still working for map load

Comment: Client and server versions needs to be the same, even patch releases.

But good that the issue you are seeing is gone.